# Is there an OOTB method to move all list versions up to the main list?

Tags: list, list-view

I have been asked to move all the versions saved in a sharepoint version controlled list to the main list level so that you can easily dump these to an excel file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy the Excel files and preserve their version history?  If so:

Try saving the List as a template (via the List Settings Menu).  This recreates all the columns you need in the destination list.

Create a Sharepoint Designer Workflow to copy the items over - I have used a 2010 workflow, although we use SP 2013.  Either 2010 or 2013 workflows are compatible for me.  You've not mentioned which version of SP you are using.

I created a column called `Send item to 2015-17 list?` - it is a Yes/No column.  When I select Yes in the column, it counts as modifying the item, therefore the workflow is triggered to run.  The next part of the workflow copies the current item to the destination (in my case it is a Document Library called `Route Cards 2015-2017` - you select the new document library you created from your saved template here).

[image: picture of a simple copy item workflow]

Remember to set the starting conditions of your `copy item workflow`:

[image: workflow start options]